# ajax post wont return from node website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a simple website where I make an ajax call to the server, which saves a bit of data, and is supposed to let the client know everything has gone through. I've made the website using node.js.

It all works great when I run locally. But when I try to connect to the website once I've launched it to aws, the ajax post never returns. It definitely makes it to the server and the data is saved, but the client never receives the return. I'm at a total loss of what might be happening.

Here is the code.

**Client Script**

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{"email":"' + $('.best_email').text() + '","guestlist":"' + $('.guest_names').text() + '","songs":"' + $('.song_request').text() + '","dietary":"' + $('.dietary').text() + '","attending":"'+$( 'input[name="attending"]:checked' ).val()+'","punting":"'+$( '#punting_choice' ).is(':Checked')+'"}',
        url: '/save_rsvp',
        async: true,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(args){
            alert('success!');
        },
        error: function(args){
            alert('failure');

        }
         //success: success_rsvp,
    });
```

**Server side script**

```
// Survey functions
router.post('/save_rsvp', function(req, res) {
  // Loads db objects
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.collection('rsvp');

  // Saves object
  collection.save(req.body,function(err, docs) {
    res.status('reply').send('{"message":"success!","id":req.body._id}');
  });
});
```

Comment: any errors in youir console at all?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Place a `console.log` in your save callback on the server. Does it run? If it does, then the problem is surely with the `res.status('reply').send(...)` line. I've never seen `.status('reply')` before. Is that a library you're using?

Comment: have you tried using .done(), .fail(), or .always()? do these return anything?